# coinciding faces - how can I remove both of them

Tags: modeling

Is there an easy way of removing these two faces at the same time as I extrude to make them overlap each other? I also would like the coinciding edges (and vertices) to merge. I am using Blender 2.8 if it matters.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want a hole through the mesh. Before you extrude, turn on snapping to vertex. [image: Snapping to vertex] Now extrude and snap to one of the vertices of the back face. This way the faces will be exactly overlapping. Now just delete them with <kbd>X</kbd>. At the end do Remove Doubles from the Vertex menu. The vertices will be joined.

[image: Cutout example]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. And it helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is *Bridge Edge Loops* command (in 2.8 is called the same as in 2.79, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). The operator connects 2 edge loops (in this case those which were forming faces) and remove those faces which become redundant.

[image]

Default settings of the operator fit well for this case, *Open Loop*, no merging.

[Bridge Edge Loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops)